# chrome profiler producing seemingly random results

Tags: javascript, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to determine which of three ways of calculating something is fastest. To determine this I simply loop a large number of times calling each and expect to look in the profiler to see how long each took.

Profiling with both firefox + firebug and IE 9 developer tools gives reasonable results, showing how much time was spent in each function. In Google Chrome though, I never see all three functions in the profile results, and worse, it shows different functions each time, but never all three. I continue to get different looking results each time I run the profiler.

I'm assuming the profiler works and I just don't know how to use it, but this sure seems broken to me. I dont see anything to explain this behavior in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling). (I was using normal release but also tried developer release (Version 26.0.1410.10 dev-m) to see if it worked better - it didn't. Increasing the number of times the loop is run, didn't seem to help either)

Sample Firebug results (shows the 3 functions + run and onClick as expected):
[image]

Sample Chrome results #1 (shows only 1 of the 3):
[image: Chrome profiler results #1]

Sample Chrome results #2 (shows 2 of the 3):
[image: Chrome profiler results #2]

The code being profiled is:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="run()">Run Test</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var R = 6371,
            toRad = Math.PI / 180;

        function haversine1(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
            var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * toRad,
                dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * toRad,
                a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                    Math.cos(lat1 * toRad) * Math.cos(lat2 * toRad) *
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2),
                c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            return (R * c);
        }

        function haversine2(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
            lat1 = lat1 * toRad;
            lon1 = lon1 * toRad;
            lat2 = lat2 * toRad;
            lon2 = lon2 * toRad;
            var dLat = lat2 - lat1,
                dLon = lon2 - lon1,
                a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                    Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2),
                c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            return (R * c);
        }

        function lawOfCosines(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
            lat1 = lat1 * toRad;
            lon1 = lon1 * toRad;
            lat2 = lat2 * toRad;
            lon2 = lon2 * toRad;
            return Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
                                Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
                                Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R;
        }

        function run() {
            console.log('Test start');
            var lat1 = 90,
                lat2 = -90,
                lon1 = 180,
                lon2 = -180,
                i = 0,
                x,
                y,
                z
            while (i++ < 1000000) {
                lat1 -= .01;
                lat2 += .01;
                lon1 -= .01;
                lon2 += .01;

                if (lat1 < -90) lat1 = 90;
                if (lat2 > 90) lat2 = -90;
                if (lon1 < -180) lon1 = 180;
                if (lon2 > 180) lon2 = -180;

                x = haversine1(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                y = haversine2(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                z = lawOfCosines(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);

                if (i % 1000 === 0) {
                    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y + ' z: ' + z);
                }
            }
            console.log('Test end');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update: When Chrome is restarted, I sometimes get expected results (i.e. I see statistics for all 3 test methods) the first time I profile. (I have a hard time believing what it reports though, as it claims the simpler method the other browsers find marginally fastest to be exponentially slower then the others) Seems to be a Chrome profiler bug. It doesn't seem to work very well for a very simple case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome DevTools uses [statistical cpu profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)
It scans javascript call stack 1000 times per second.
As a result it gets many stack traces and combines them into a call tree.

pros: Small degradation of the executing javascript code.

cons: it will show incorrect results for js code that runs less than 0.5 second.

I'd recommend to use a separate cycle for each function, remove console.log and increase counter value. Also v8 may inline the body of the function and I'm not sure that the profiler is able to count the inlined code separately.

Comment: That seems to work. I had previously tried increasing the counter value but not a separate cycle for each. Makes me wonder though, how well the profiler works when profiling real code that is not written to satisfy the profiler. Though I suppose if the missed code is so fast that it inst detected during a scan, its probably not the bottleneck you are searching for... (I do still have a hard time believing the results though, it claims a mathematically simpler computation takes orders of magnitude longer then a more complex one)

Comment: There is a chance that the slowest function could not be optimized.

Comment: There is a chance that the slowest function could not be optimized.
By default V8 generates a generic code and monitor the performance.
If a function is hot then it generates more specific version of the function based on the information it collected about the functio. Sometimes it does de optimization due to some reason. http://floitsch.blogspot.ca/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-introduction.html

Comment: I did another round of tests and with help of Date.now() I found that actually the speed is the same for all the cases.

Comment: So it could be a CPU profiler problem with inlined functions and a kind of interference between profiler sampling rate and the function calling rate.